# read.csv.sql with empty commas

Tags: r, sqldf

I have a csv file with fixed headers. But some of the column values can be missing with empty commas. This is creating problems for read.csv.sql. Am I missing any parameter for this function? I expect to read null/NA - is there any workaround?

sample file content -

> day,car1,car2
>
> 1,bmw,audi
>
> 2,merc,bmw
>
> 3,,audi
>
> 4,,

I get this error -

Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :
line 1 did not have 45 elements

Comment: I cannot reproduce that error with your example; the following code works as expected without error: ```library(sqldf); tmp <-tempfile(); write("day,car1,car2 \n 1,bmw,audi \n 2,merc,bmw \n 3,,audi \n 4,,",   file = tmp); read.csv.sql(tmp); unlink(tmp)```

Comment: I think I deleted my comment by mistake: I had asked to see the read.csv command & the options you had used.

Comment: Thanks. After close examination I found that the number of commas were not matching! It works now.

Comment: I was having difficulty because the original file was ~500MB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The huge file was first split into smaller chunks. The `csv` was then opened with Excel with `,` as de-limiter. There was a mis-match in number of commas in header(45 elements) and the next line(43 elements).